# Apache Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) ProxyPass

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

I'm trying to configure a simple ProxyPass using this file (as simple as possible) linked in /etc/apache2/sites-enable form sites-avalable (same file seems to work on apache 2.2 but may be i have done other configuration on previous installation and i canìt remember those configuration)
Note i use an IPADDRESS and not a Server Name but i think this is not the problem.
Note 2: i'm not an apache web server expert :)!

```
ServerName IP_SERVER_ADDRESS

# Redmine
ProxyPass        /redmine   http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:8555/redmine

# test1
ProxyPass        "/test1"   "http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:9180/test1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/test1"   "http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:9180/test1/"

# test2
ProxyPass        /test2   http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:8880/test2
ProxyPassReverse /test2   http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:8880/test2

DocumentRoot /var/www
```

But it didn't work, so the url

```
http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS:8880/test2
```

work fine , but the proxied url

```
http://IP_SERVER_ADDRESS/test2
```

did not work , with the error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /redmine was not found on this server
```

Output of  apache2ctl -S seems strange as apparently no VirtualHost configuration is used (?)

```
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Quite sure i'm missing some simple thing but i can't find it!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is tested in Apache Apache/2.4.7 (Debian) ProxyPass.

See /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

previous version was

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

So basically in apache 2.4 (Debian and derivated) you must use file with a .conf extension to limit headache....
In Apache 2.2 the  .conf extension in file name is not needed.

Other Details:

1. In sites-enabled configuration files (a soft link to sites-available) MUST be have an extension .conf so WHATEVER_YOU_WANT.**conf**
2. You MUST use a2ensite to enable a configuration, because if the file in sites-available did not have the "right" extension ".conf" it say "ERROR: Site WHATEVER_YOU_WANT does not exist!". So for example if you use a file named *mysite* and try to enable the configuration mysite with the command *"a2ensite mysite"* you receive an error. If you use a file named *myfile.conf* same command  will work fine... If you manually create a soft link in sites-enabled to a conf file without the "conf" extension , the site will not work!!
3. You can create a soft link in sites-available with the right extension (.conf) to a file WITHOUT the right extension alredy peresent in sites-available. In such a case the configuration will work but if you use a2dissite to disable the site it will say "ERROR: Site WHATEVER_YOU_WANT does not exist!"

After finding the solution i found some link around 
https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/updating-virtual-host-settings-from-apache-2-2-to-apache-2-4